# memory layout of vector<bool>

Tags: vector, boolean, memory-layout

Can someone please explain the memory layout of the data stored in a `vector<bool>`?

like what layout does the memory have from address `&myVec[0]` upwards? Does it depend on endianness? Is the memory continguous for all stored values? (i'm aware that `vector<bool>` doesn't actually store booleans). can I dump the content of a `vector<bool>` into a file using memcopy to get a bitmap of my values?

please no questions like "what do you need it for" or suggestions like using bitsets or boost.

Thank you for an accurate explanation

Comment: The standard does not mention an explicit memory layout for obvious reasons, just that a specialization is offered for space efficiency, and how access to single bits is simulated by a reference type.

Comment: what do you mean by "and how access to single bits is simulated by a reference type" ?

Comment: To quote the standard:"*reference is a class that simulates the behavior of references of a single bit in vector<bool>*" - it's used in the interface declaration of std::vector<bool>

Answer (score 1):

The std::vector will simply manage a raw array on the heap. So whan you do &myVec[0] you get the address of the first element of this array. As it's an array it...follows the rules of a raw array..

BUT

std::vector is a special case, a specific implementation, a mistake of the C++ commitee that is NOT a vector of `bool` but a container managing bits. So avoid using this one.

Comment: i'm aware of that and would like to know about the used memorylayout for the bits

Comment: I'm not sure what exact information you need but arrays are guaranteed to be contiguous block of memory. Other than that it follows the padding rules for the platform by default.

Answer (score 0):

A vector is essentially a wrapper around an array so yes, the memory is contiguous. This also means you can use memcpy on it (if that's what you want).

The endianness of each element depends on your current architecture.

```
vector<bool> myvector;
myvector.push_back(1);
myvector.push_back(0);
myvector.push_back(0);
myvector.push_back(1);
myvector.push_back(0);
myvector.push_back(1);
myvector.push_back(1);
myvector.push_back(0);
```

would appear like this in memory:

```
1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0
```

I'm not sure if that is what you are asking.

Comment: but `vector<bool>` uses single bits to store the boolean values and i'd like to know about the order of those bits

Comment: yes that's what I was asking. so if there are 13 booleans in a `vector<bool>` they are stored as 13 consecutive bits in memory?